# how to create sticky session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to Create sticky Session, and what kind of session is usefull for sticky Session and load balancing  please answer. Thanks

```html
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=<IPADDRESSOFTHESERVER>:42424"
cookieless="false" timeout="100"/>


  
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="20"/>



<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="100"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194328/enabling-sticky-sessions-on-a-load-balancer

Comment: but this post does not show how to create sticky session

Comment: See TechNet guidance on ["Single Affinity"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734910.aspx)

Comment: i read this article, but how to create sticky session in asp.net which session good for load balancing

Comment: Sorry, i thought it might help you. What is your network architecture, and why you need a sticky session?

Comment: You don't create a sticky session with asp.net, that is a function of your load balancer.  What you can do is use an appropriate session state mechanic, which the link by MK Wierzba and the answer by Win both give you information about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Session-State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) offers 3 modes for load balancing - StateServer, SQLServer and Custom.

If your application do not use **Cache**, you can use either one of three. *I personally like SQLServer over StateServer, but SQLServer is not cheap.*

However, if you use Cache, you want to use **Custom** mode to store Session-State in a cache. *For example, Redis Cache.*